# Python How to share data like skype?

Tags: python, tcp, udp

I'm trying to make 2 programs "speak" to each-other, other the whole internet. I've tried using tcp connection, im very new to it and so fare i find that it's only goes through if its in lan, or you do some port forwarding and stuff.
What does programs share information without getting to trouble with firewall and port forwarding?
I just need to know what can be used for it and whats preferred, so that i can look in to it my self.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching nuff said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Dweet](http://dweet.io/), you can use a simple `urllib` request to push and pull data in a JSON format.

Comment: Have you figured it out RasmusGP?

Comment: Non quite, but havent spent enough time on it, but so fare it looks like what i need ;)

Comment: Just as you would type the link in the browser, you can simulate it with `urllib.urlopen`.